# If $f'(z_0)\neq 0$ then $f$ is one to one on some open disk $D_r(z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is what I am trying to prove

> Let $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ be open and $f$ be analytic in $D$. If there is $z_0\in D$ such that $f'(z_0)\neq 0$ then there exists $D_r(z_0)\subset D$ and $f$ is one to one in $D_r(z_0)$.

I am finding it difficult to prove this but on some disk $D_r(z_0)\subset D$ $f'=0$ due to continuity. But I just can't go ahead and get anything out of this. ANy hints will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you use the inverse function theorem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: @ajotatxe I don't know much about but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of the [inverse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Notes_on_methods_of_proof) theorem which tells you something more: the inverse function is itself differentiable.

If you just want to prove that your function is one-to-one in a small circle you might reason as follows.

Consider the incremental ratio:
$$
  g(w,z) = \frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}
$$
and define $g(z,z) = f'(z)$ so that $g$ results in a continuous function defined on $D\times D$. You know that $|g(z_0,z_0)| = |f'(z_0)|=c>0$. Take $r>0$ small enough so that $|g(z,w)| > c/2$ for all $z,w \in D_r(z_0)$. Then:
$$
 |f(z)-f(w)| = |g(z,w)(z-w)| = |g(z,w)|\cdot |z-w| \ge \frac c 2 |z-w| > 0
$$ 
if $z\neq w$.
Hence the function is one-to-one.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very similar to Donald Edwards answer but I just can't seem to see the exact connection

Comment: $\varphi(z) = g(z,z_0)$ in @Donald_Edwards answer. In fact in his answer you find $f(z)\neq f(z_0)$ and you should complete the reasoning by also varying $z_0$... which is not completely trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The [Lagrange inversion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) says that if $f'(z_0)\neq 0$ then $f$ is invertible near $z_0$.

The theorem gives an explicit power series for the inverse function.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/334245/.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: An idea, why it should be true. On a small disk the higher derivatives are meaningless, hence the graph of the function is near a plane on this disk.

Comment: What do u mean by near a plane?

Comment: @Heisenberg Near $f(z)=f(z_0)+Ax+By$, where $z=(x,y)$, $A$ and $B$ are not both equal to zero.

Comment: This approach, if sound, would prove the same result for functions differentiable in the real sense... and said result is wrong. So, no, this is definitely not "an idea why it should be true".

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $r>0$ such that $f'(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in D(z_0,r)$. First prove that $\tilde{f}=f|_{D(z_0,r)}$ is injective. Suppose that $\tilde{f}$ is not injective. By [Complex Mean Value Theorem](http://planetmath.org/complexmeanvaluetheorem) for all $z_1,z_2 \in D(z_0,r) $there are $u,v\in D(z_0,r)$ such that
$$
\mbox{Re}\{\tilde{f}(u)\}=\mbox{Re}\left\{\frac{\tilde{f}(z_2)-\tilde{f}(z_1)}{z_2-z_1}\right\},
\\
\mbox{Im}\{\tilde{f}(v)\}=\mbox{Im}\left\{\frac{\tilde{f}(z_2)-\tilde{f}(z_1)}{z_2-z_1}\right\}.
$$
Use this to get a contradiction and conclude that $\tilde{f}$ is injective. For sufficiently small disk of radius $r>0$ have to $\tilde{f}$ is surjective. Thus $\tilde{f}$ is $1-1$.